# Redirection from one domain to other excluding one directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

I am trying to create a permanent htaccess redirect (301) from all files in one directory in one domain, to another domain sub-directory as follows:

Redirect all files in the following directory:

from: www.xxx.com/abc/xyz/faq.html

to: www.yyy.com/xyz/faq.html

want to remove apps folder while redirecting

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ignore_dir/(.*) https://m.mydomain.com/abc/%{REQUEST_URI}  [L,R=302]